# Perl how to organize code between subroutines and main script

Tags: perl

I got one perl script which has main script and a couple subroutines interleaved together. It looks like:

```
sub utils1 {
  ...
}

# some code
# some more code that calls utils1

sub utils2 {
  ...
}

# some code that calls utils2

sub utils3 {
  ...
}

# some code that calls utils3
# the rest of code
```

Is there a better way to organize the code? Looking for a good coding convention. Based on my python coding experience, I am thinking something like below. How does that look?

```
sub utils1 {
  ...
}

sub utils2 {
  ...
}

sub utils3 {
  ...
}

sub main {
    # some code
    # some more code that calls utils1
    # some code that calls utils2
    # some code that calls utils3
    # the rest of code
}

&main();
```

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using? Why are you using `&` with `main()`? This might be of use to you: http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices/

Comment: Small point: perl subroutines are declared using `sub`, not `subroutine`...

Comment: There's a great (free!) guide to modern perl practices at [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/index.html).

Comment: In a nutshell, the format you're planning to use should do.. However, please follow the syntax and recommendations suggested by other users in comments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no [best-practice](http://www.perlcritic.org/) defined for the organization of subroutines. From my experience the documentation often dictates the order.

E.g.

```
use Getopt::Lucid;

=head1 SYNOPSIS

This program does nothing so long ...

=cut

# ... main code here, not necessary to wrap into a sub

=head1 PUBLIC METHODS

=cut

sub method1 {

=head2 method1

This method does something ...

=cut

    $self = shift;
    # ...
}

sub method2 {

=head2 method2

This method does something different...

=cut

    $self = shift;
    # ...
}

=head1 PRIVATE METHODS

These methods are private their interface may change.

=cut

sub _priv1 {

=head2 _priv1

The _priv1 method is for ... and used by ....

=cut

    my $self = shift;
    # ...
}
```